# I can't turn off my apps cellular data on my iphone, Help!

Tags: applications, iphone, cellular-data

I try to disable the cellular data for my apps in my iphone 4 running ios 7.1.2, then i did it, but when i push the back button from cellular setting page and reopen it, the apps cellular data was **turning back on**, please help if there are any solutution for this

Answer (score 4):

I had this same problem. The apps that I didn't want to use for cellular and every time I would close out of settings or disable cellular data the apps would re-enable again, but I managed to restore my iPhone I had to set it up as a new iPhone. I advise if you are having a problem like this to write down all your apps or contacts or important stuff down, So you can use for reference. Or you can backup important stuff via iTunes and iCloud. But by me restoring my iPhone and setting it as a new phone resolved the problem. I hope this helps.

Comment: Nice. So the preference file or database that stores that setting was corrupt and throwing away all settings allowed you to make changes again to at setting.

Comment: Yep. Tried many ways, only this one worked.